# Convert generic list of class A and B with same properties to List of class C using generics

Tags: c#, list, generics, types

I have 3 classes, DOb, Patient, and LookUp

```
public class Dog
    {  public int Id { get; set; }
        public DateTime DOB { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string Display { get; set; }
        public int qqQMS { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }

public class Patient
    {
       public int Id { get; set; }
        public Guid Patid { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string Display { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }
 public class LookUp : ILookUp
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Display { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }
```

I am trying to easily take a list or List convert it to List  I asked this question before and never figured it out, with out using a Dynamic, I would rather have a smoother way without Dynamics

I have tried

```
 List<LookUp> Look = doggy.Cast<LookUp>().ToList();

  List<LookUp> patLook = pat.Cast<LookUp>().ToList();
```

also tried this but I am not happy with it

```
public static IList<LookUp> ToLookUp<T>( IEnumerable<T> source)  
        {
            List<LookUp> list = (from prop in source
                                 select new LookUp
                                 {
                                     Display = prop.Display ?? "",
                                     Description = prop.Description ?? "",
                                     Id = prop.Id
                                 }).ToList();
            return list;
        }
```

an extension method could work

Comment: Is Automapper an option?

Comment: not on the approved list, the client has a list of nuget and 3rd party libraries that are approved, if something is not on the list it takes 3 to 6 months to get it approved

Answer (score 0):

You will need to implement the *interface* on your *classes*, the concrete `Lookup` *class* is not needed at this point:

```
public class Dog : ILookUp { ... }

public class Patient : ILookUp { ... }
```

That way you can cast to your interface and use it:

```
var listOfDogs = new List<dog>();

var LookupList = listOfDogs.Cast<ILookup>();
```

---

> I would love to but Dob ad Patient are created else where and I cannot
>   modify them

Then there is no easier way to do this, you can't really make a generic solution without reflection, you will have to *project* to `Lookup` as you are doing, or make an expression for each type.

Comment: I would love to but Dob ad Patient are created else where and I cannot modify them